# Open Dialog via dynamic menu

Tags: android, menu, dialog

How can I open a dialog with some html formatting and hypertext link support (open that link in default browser), when I click on item: "ABOUT" in my dynamically created menu?
Also, how I can make SHARE function, so that if anybody click on: "SHARE" item, it will either share link to that APK, or send it over bluetooth?

This is what I have in MainActivity:

```
private static final int NEW_MENU_ID=Menu.FIRST+1;
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, NEW_MENU_ID, 0, "ABOUT");
        menu.add(0, NEW_MENU_ID, 0, "SHARE");

        return true;
    }
```

And this is how it should look like:
[image: template]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's two big and completely different questions and too little code presented.

First of all You should give different options id in onCreateOptionsMenu (let them be ID_ABOUT == 0 and ID_SHARE == 1) override  [onOptionsItemSelected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case ID_ABOUT:
        handleAbout();
        break;

    case ID_SHARE:
        handleShare();
        break;
    }
}
```

No handleAbout() and handleShare() should be defined (that's your questions about):

- ABOUT: probably, the easiest way is to create additional activity which would contain only one [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). First activity would just start AboutActivity from handleAbout();
- SHARE: it's quite common task. Please, refer to android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) and for example, to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431386/android-share-intent-chooser)

Answer (score 1):

```
1. how could I open dialog with some html formatting and hypertext link support (open that link in default browser), when I click on item: "ABOUT" in my dynamically created menu?
```

Look at this SO Question: [Android hyperlinks on TextView in custom AlertDialog not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069811/android-hyperlinks-on-textview-in-custom-alertdialog-not-clickable/12070751#12070751)

```
2. how I can make SHARE function, so that if anybody click on: "SHARE" item, it will either share link to that APK, or send it over bluetooth?
```

Use **Android Intent** with `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. Which will share the link of .apk file on available application on device which handle SHARE Intent.

and  to send APK via Bluetooth .. either use same **Intent** with `ACTION_SEND` action or You have to implement Bluetooth file transfer code..

Look at this SO Question: [bluetooth file transfer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573761/bluetooth-file-transfer-in-android)